# How to get data attributes value from child elements in angular controllers

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Yesterday I start learning `AngularJs` online. I decided to create some useful stuffs for my new project using `Angular`. Below is some portion of my hard work :

**The HTML Part**

```
<div data-ng-controller="DataGrid_Controller">
    <table class="table table-stripped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="fname"> First Name </th>
                <th data-field="lname"> Last Name </th>
                <th data-field="email"> Email </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**The Angular Part**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('TestApp',[]);

app.controller('DataGrid_Controller', function($scope){
    //var fields = ['fname', 'lname', 'email']; 
    //How can I get the value of data-field attributes in my 'Controller' so that I could use them 
})
</script>
```

How can I get the value of `data-attributes` from child elements (I don't know either the term `element` exists or not in angular?) in my controller.

I am 1 day old baby for `AngularJs` so please show me the right way if you think I am catching the wrong way of doing it. I have used `jQuery` for years so I am thinking a `controller` as `plugin`. Please help me solving the problem.

Comment: It looks like you're doing it backwards. The template should display value from the data stored in the scope. You're trying to get data from the template. controllers shouldn't deal with HTML elements. If you told us what you want to achieve, at a higher level, it would be easier to help.

Comment: @JBNizet I want to create 'plugin' which gets the values from the database and displays it in html table. The user (for now me) should be able to specify which fields to retrieve from database table within the markup (you called it template).

Comment: By "the user", I assume you mean "the developer". The controller scope should contain an array of JavaScript objects, and the markup should use `{{ user.firstName }}`(for example) to display the user first name.

Comment: @JBNizet If I specified the fields within the controller it self, then how can I reuse that controller for making other `datagrids`? An example code will be helpful because I am not going to understand until I get it working. Sorry for my childish behavior.

Comment: If you want to use controller in other `datagrids`, then what logic that controleer should realize?

Comment: use directive to access attributes. If you haven't gone through turtorial on docs site step-by-step...do it. well worth the time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Angular, you need to think in terms of model, not the resulted DOM. The model is the only source of truth. So, you need to put your headers somewhere in your model. Then you make a loop through you data, and for each item you iterate over headers and create a table. You'll need a directive to work woth DOM, a controller to contain the data and a simple template:

**The DOM:**

```
<div data-ng-controller="DataGrid">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-header="firstName" data-headers="headers">
          First name
        </th>
        <th data-header="lastName" data-headers="headers">
          Last name
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-ng-repeat="character in characters">
        <td data-ng-repeat="header in headers">
          {{character[header]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Angular application:**

```
'use strict';

var DataAttributes = angular.module('DataAttributes', []);
```

**Datagrid controller:**

```
'use strict';

DataAttributes.controller('DataGrid', ['$scope', function($scope){
    // let this data came from server
    $scope.characters = [
        {
            'firstName' : 'Anakin',
            'lastName' : 'Skywalker',
            'email' : 'annie@tatooi.ne',
            'age' : 9
        },
        {
            'firstName' : 'Kos',
            'lastName' : 'Palpatine',
            'email' : 'sidius@darksiders.com',
            'age' : 60
        },
        {
            'firstName' : 'Jar',
            'lastName' : 'Jar',
            'email' : 'stupid@nab.oo',
            'age' : 23
        }
    ];

    $scope.headers = [];
}]);
```

**And a directive:**

```
'use strict';

DataAttributes.directive('header', [function(){
    return {
        'restrict' : 'A',
        'scope' : {
            'headers' : '='
        },
        'link' : function(scope, iElement, iAttrs){
            scope.headers.push(iAttrs['header']);
        }
    };
}]);
```

I've created a [plunkr, so you can play with it](http://plnkr.co/edit/7Js1EN9NAnhdGDl5iOED?p=preview).

Let's see what is under the hood. Suppose you've already got your data (`characters`) somewhere else. Now you want to dynamically build a table with some fields from it. You create a directive to capture field name (`header`). It need to put header names in the controllers's scope. So, you need to bind a model from parent scope, to directive's. This is achieved with `'headers' : '='` line, which [tells Angular to](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile#description_comprehensive-directive-api_directive-definition-object)

> set up bi-directional binding between a local scope property and the parent scope property of name defined via the value of the attr attribute. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name.

The directive simply pushes field names to parent scope. Now, `ngRepeat` can be used to iterate through them and render a row for each element from `characters`. That's it!

Comment: Before reading your answers I learned `Angular JS` books thoroughly and now I am able to understand your code. This is really a fine way to solve my problem. Thank you for your `plunkr` also.